# Boolean Algebra simplify

Tags: boolean-algebra

The question is to simplify

$$xy'z+wxy'z'+wxy+w'x'y'z'+w'x'yz'$$

Using K-map, the answer is $wx + w'x'z' + xy'z$

However, the question wants me to simplify algebraically, stating laws beside.

I tried it for hours but it's just so hard I can't do it by myself.

It's due tomorrow So I need help please..

Thank You!

Comment: no it's not a typo

Comment: For one, notice that you have $w'x'y'z'$ and $w'x'yz'$. Obviously, the switch for $y$ has no bearing on the circuit and so can be eliminated to give a component $w'x'z'$

Answer (score 0):

I don’t want to say too much, since it’s an assignment, but here’s a rough roadmap.

Notice that the terms $w'x'y'z'$ and $w'x'yz'$ have three factors in common, so you can use a distributive law to pull them out and reduce $w'x'y'z'+w'x'yz'$ to $w'x'z'(y'+y)$, which you should be able to simplify using two laws.

The next bit is the tricky part. Use an absorption law to expand $xy'z$ to $xy'z+wxy'z$. Then simplify $wxy'z+wxy'z'$, and combine the result with $wxy$.

Answer (score 0):

xy′z+wxy′z′+wxy+w′x′y′z′+w′x′yz′

(w'+w)xy′z + wxy′z′     + wxy   +w′x′y′z′ + w′x′yz′ -> multiply first minterm with (w'+w)

w'xy'z     + wxy'z      + wxy'z'+ wxy     +w′x′z'(y'+y) -> reduce last two minterms

w'xy'z     + wxy'(z+z') + wxy   + w'x'z' -> group 2 and 3rd minterms

w'xy'z     + wxy'       + wxy   + w'x'z' -> 2 min term reduces

w'xy'z     + wx(y'+y)   + w'x'z' -> group 2nd and 3rd minterm, and reorder minterms

wx         + w'x'z'     + w'xy'z

I think the last minterm in your answer is wrong.

Comment: I generated my answer with circuits and truth tables with the original expression, my answer has identical outputs as the question... I dont know your work looks great but there may be something wrong and I can't even spot it..